# Use a variable to set the size of a bitset

Tags: c++

I'm wondering how I would go about using a variable to set the size of a bitset. For example,

```
// obtain file size:
fseek (rFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
numberOfBytes = ftell (rFile);
rewind (rFile);

const unsigned long long buffSize = numberOfBytes * 8;
std::bitset<buffSize> buffer;
```

I get a error message saying that the value of buffSize is unusable in a constant expression. I'm looking for a way to set the bitset to the size of whatever file I'm currently reading.

Comment: You cannot use variables as template parameters, neither you can use non const variables to initialize const variables. It's a cruel world but you have to swallow that.

Comment: How would the compiler know how to size that thing if you won't tell it a constant value? Some Standard Library containers can be sized arbitrarily after compilation, others can't. Read the documentation carefully to know the difference.

Comment: May be you can get off with `std::vector<bool>` as a poor solution.

Comment: side note: why are u using C file functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can't be done. The size of a `std:bitset` is a template parameter, so it has to be a compile-time constant.

A few choices that can/could work would be:

1. Set an upper bound on the size, use a `bitset` of that size, and just ignore the extra bits.
2. Switch to an `std::vector<bool>`. This has caveats, but provides roughly similar basic capabilities as a `bitset`.
3. Switch to a Boost [`dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html). This will let you specify the size as a parameter to the ctor, rather than a template parameter, so it doesn't need to be a compile-time constant.

There are undoubtedly other possibilities, of course. Personally, my first choice would probably be the Boost `dynamic_bitset`.

Comment: `vector<bool>` would obviously take 8 times the memory though.

Comment: @mooncrater: might seem obvious, but it's generally wrong. `vector` has a specialization for `bool` that uses a packed representation, so they're essentially the same size.

Comment: Damn! That's something new! Can you lead me to some sources for this?

Comment: @Mooncrater: that's been required since the 1998 standard (and it wasn't really new then). C++98, §[lib.vector.bool]/1 says: "To optimize space allocation, a specialization of vector for bool elements is provided:" (and then goes on to define the interface to the specialized class, where: "`reference` is a class that simulates the behavior of references of a single bit in vector<bool>."

Comment: New for me though! Thanks!

Comment: You're certainly welcome. You should probably also be aware that some people think providing this specialization was a mistake--it means a `vector<bool>` is different from any other vector in some subtle (and sometimes not even very subtle) ways.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different types of constants, compile time constants and everything else that is declared `const`.  In your code you have the latter.  Even though it is declared as `const` is is initialized with data that is not known until run time so it is not a compile time constant.

`std::bitset` needs to be defined with a compile time constant.  Since you do not have one the compiler gives you an error.  If you need a bitset defined at runtime I would suggest [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the size needs to be known at compile time